# How do I configure WIFI in ParrotOS?

Tags: linux, mate, parrot-os

I have tried creating a WIFI connection with advanced network configuration to no avail.

I have an Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 WIFI adaptor, upon updating the drivers I have found that I am using up to date drivers.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Uhmmm, I read the Debian user manual, and consulted their website.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with the network configuration of Parrot OS by default, so this is likely an issue with your device or Network Card

Comment: You may need to install drivers. Please use `lspci` (for internal hardware) or `lsusb` (for USB devices) to find out your exact model, then [edit] the question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

To check which driver you need type the command on terminal
sudo lsusb
Search the output list for something like 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
This b728 can be something else, and this will determine driver required.
GoogleSearch"0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp DRIVER"
You may first install the building tools first via command:
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
sudo apt-get install mokutil && mokutil --sb-state
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git (SEARCH CHIPSET in search option of github.com for repositories available with that file)
Type these command on terminal:-
cd rtw88
make
sudo make install

Now you're going to remove the folder with the driver building blocks, which has become useless.
Type these command:-
rm -v -R --interactive=never ~/rtw88
If the installation success, run 2 commands load the new driver.
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
sudo reboot
For more information go to this website https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html